# Can I access python variables within a `%%bash` or `%%script` ipython notebook cell?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipython-magic

Is there a way to access variables in the current python kernel from within a `%%bash` or other `%%script` cell?

Perhaps as command line arguments or environment variable(s)?

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Python variables can be accessed in the first line of a `%%bash` or `%%script` cell, and so can be passed as command line parameters to the script. For example, with bash you can do this:

```
%%bash -s "$myPythonVar" "$myOtherVar"
echo "This bash script knows about $1 and $2"
```

The `-s` command line option allows you to pass positional parameters to bash, accessed through `$n` for the n-th positional parameter. Note that what's actually assigned to the bash positional variable is the result of `str(myPythonVariable)`. If you're passing strings containing quote characters (or other bash-sensitive characters), you'll need to escape them with a backslash (eg: `\"`).

The quotes are important - without them the python variables (string representations) are split on spaces, so if `myPythonVar` was a `datetime.datetime` with `str(myPythonVar)` as `"2013-10-30 05:04:09.797507"`, the above bash script would receive 3 positional variables, the first two with values `2013-10-30` and `05:04:09.797507`. It's output would be:

```
This bash script knows about 2013-10-30 and 05:04:09.797507
```

If you want to name the variables and you're running linux, here's an approach:

```
%%script env my_bash_variable="$myPythonVariable" bash
echo myPythonVariable\'s value is $my_bash_variable
```

You can specify multiple variable assignments. Again beware of quotes and other such things (here bash will complain bitterly!). To grok why this works, see the `env` man page.

Comment: 11 years later, this doesn't seem to work anymore.

Answer (score 77):

To include python variables within bash commands run using the syntax `!<some command>` you can use `{<variable>}` as follows:

```
In [1]: for i in range(3):
   ...:     !echo {i+1}
   ...:     
1
2
3
```

While this is slightly different from what the OP asked, it is closely related and useful in performing a scripting task.  [This post](https://web.archive.org/web/20160914042017/safaribooksonline.com/blog/2014/02/12/using-shell-commands-effectively-ipython/) has more great tips and examples of using shell command within IPython and Jupyter notebooks.

Comment: Link is broken. Cached in the WIA: https://web.archive.org/web/20160914042017/safaribooksonline.com/blog/2014/02/12/using-shell-commands-effectively-ipython/

Comment: Thanks @awalllllll, just replaced the link.

Comment: This is great, thanks. Looks quite hacky, but I think it is the whole purpose of jupyter notebooks.

Comment: would never have guessed you can just use `!` so willy-nilly. You can even do `n = !echo {i + 1}`.

Comment: iPython is so cool. I love it!

Answer (score 9):

One problem is, if the variable that you want to give to your bash is a list, it does not work as expected.

For example, in one python cell:

```
l = ['A', 'B', 'C']
```

then if you give it directly to the magic option the next cell:

```
%%bash -s "$l"
for i in $1
do
echo $i
done
```

It will be oddly split like this:

```
['A',
'B',
'C']
```

The simplest answer is to put code inside braces `{}` to transform your python list in bash list, like the following:

```
%%bash -s "{" ".join(l)}"
for i in $1
do
echo $i
done
```

Which give the expected output:

```
A
B
C
```

Comment: odd that the use of double quotes inside double quotes works (: Seems the `%%bash` magic is looking for a `}` and isn't concerned about it.

Answer (score 9):

If someone like me ends up here looking for how to use Python variables when running commands with `!`, just add prefix the variable with `$` and that should do it:

```
!echo $foobar
```

Answer (score 5):

Just to note a variation, if you need to pass something other than a simple variable to the bash script:

```
%%bash -s $dict['key1'] $dict['key2'] $dict['key3']
```

goes gruesomely wrong, but

```
%%bash -s {dict['key1']} {dict['key2']} {dict['key3']}
```

works nicely.

Answer (score 5):

You can use Python string templates if you are willing to define a new magic with:

```
from IPython import get_ipython
from IPython.core.magic import register_cell_magic

ipython = get_ipython()


@register_cell_magic
def pybash(line, cell):
    ipython.run_cell_magic('bash', '', cell.format(**globals()))
```

And then if you define a variable in Python like:

```
test = 'Python variables'
```

you can use it:

```
%%pybash
echo '{test} will be expanded'
echo '{{double braces will be replaced with single braces}}'
```

Resulting in:

```
Python variables will be expanded
{double braces will be replaced with single braces}
```

Comment: This does not allow to put arbitrary expressions inside curly braces, but just the defined global variables.

Comment: Yes, format does not allow some cool features which are available in f-strings (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63121350/how-to-use-self-docummenting-equals-debugging-specifier-with-str-format). Once https://peps.python.org/pep-0501/ gets in it will be possible.

Comment: I just added my answer showing how to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by the answer from @krassowski, the following works to interpret arbitrary expressions in curly braces, with the semantics of f-strings. That is, you can use expressions such as `{1+val}` and not just `{val}`, given that the variable `val` is defined in the global python context (such as in a Jupyter notebook).

```
@register_cell_magic
def pybash(line, cell):
    cell_replaced = eval("f" + repr(cell))
    # print("Evaluating:\n{}\n-----------".format(cell_replaced))
    ipython.run_cell_magic('bash', '', cell_replaced)
```

As an example, define a global variable in a python cell:

```
val = 2
```

Then, in a new cell:

```
%%pybash
echo \\
echo {1+val}
```

This outputs

```
\
3
```

This is safe as long as the cell content is not controlled by an attacker.

Answer (score 0):

No, `%%script` magic are autogenerated and don't do any magic inter-process data communication. (which is not the case for `%%R` but which is a separate magic in its own class with extra care from `R` peoples)

But writing your own magic that does it is not too hard to do.

Comment: Did you mean something like `%%bash -c 'myvar=$MyPythonVar bash'`, then perhaps `echo $myvar` in the next line of the cell? That works...

Comment: so.. what did you have in mind? It complains if the `%%bash ..` cell has no other contents, and if I put, say, `ls` in there, the os comes back with `/bin/echo: /bin/echo: cannot execute binary file` (at least on my mac - but ubuntu does something similar i think)

Comment: Ah sorry, I read too fast I though what you were writing was working. Looking at the code the bash magic does not support `{..}` syntax except in the first line. So yo will need to write it by yourself.

Comment: ok. I found a few ways to use the first line (answer below). I guess writing a %% magic to do it better could be nicer - perhaps special comments like `#%%exppose myPythonVar` then substitute it's value into the script when you see `$myPythonVar` or something... Perhaps one day I'll give it a whirl (:

Comment: In the current jupyter, the method I proposed above doesn't seem to be working - python variables are not accessible from the first line of a %%bash cell. @Matt Can you confirm?

Comment: Yes I can confirm, I'll remove my answer.

Comment: My mistake - the variable contained an empty string, so didn't turn up. The solution in my answer above still works (: