# using python variables with bash magic in jupyter

Tags: python, bash, jupyter-notebook

I would like to run bash commands in jupyter notebook using the `%%bash` magic command and pass python variables. As described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19579546/can-i-access-python-variables-within-a-bash-or-script-ipython-notebook-c) I can do this as follows:

```
%%bash -s {foo} {bar}
cp $1 $2
```

This works just fine. However, when I have a bunch of these variables and the bash commands are long, it becomes a bit unwieldy to use `$1`, `$2`, and so on for arguments. I know that one can use the curly braces notation for line magics as follows:

```
!cp {foo} {bar}
```

Is there a comparable way to use the curly brace notation with cell magic? Perhaps something along the lines of:

```
## in a python cell
foo = 'foo.txt'
bar = 'bar.txt'

## in another cell
%%bash <SOMETHING GOES HERE>
cp {foo} {bar}
```

*UPDATE (04-14-2022)*: This can be done by defining a new magic as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67029719/6262370).

Comment: Are you actually looking for `$@` (array of positional args) in bash?

Comment: `$@` is going to return the entire list of arguments. But what I am interested in is to be able to refer to them using a name instead of numbers. I will edit the question to make it a little more clear.

Comment: Question answered by @krassowski in the post referred to by the question author (about a year after the question was asked here)

TLDR: Basically, you can use Python string templates with braces if you are willing to define new cell magic

Answer (score 8):

Try

```
!cp $foo $bar
```

Without the braces.