# How to access python variables in Sagemaker Jupyter Notebook shell command

Tags: python, bash, shell, jupyter-notebook, amazon-sagemaker

In one of the cells of Sagemaker notebook, I've set a variable

```
region="us-west-2"
```

In subsequent cell, I run following 2 shell commands

```
!echo $region
```

Output

```
us-west-2
```

However, unable to run aws shell command using this variable

```
!aws ecr get-login-password --region $region
```

`$ variable-name` doesn't help inside jupyter cell `! shell command`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19674648/5157515

There's no direct way to access python variables with `!` command.

But with magic command `%%bash` it is possible

```
%%bash  -s "$region"
aws ecr get-login-password --region $1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can now do this using brackets:

```
region = 'us-east-2'
!echo {region}
```