# How to use self-docummenting equals (debugging) specifier with str.format()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, f-string, self-documenting-code

Python 3.8 introduced `=` specifier in f-strings (see this [issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue36817) and [pull request](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/13123)).

It allows to quickly represent both the value and the name of the variable:

```
from math import pi as π
f'{π=}'
# 'π=3.141592653589793'
```

I would like to use this feature on a pre-defined string with `str.format()`:

```
'{π=}'.format(π=π)
```

However, it raises an exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'π='
```

Is there a way to make it work (e.g. with a special dunder method)?

Why it may be useful?

- one could have a programmatic template for multiple values of the same variable (in a loop)

  - in contrasts, f-strings have to be hardcoded; think about internationalization
- one could reference constants defined in a module in its docstring (`module.__doc__.format(**vars(module)`);

  - workaround: define an f-string variable at the end of the module, overwrite the `module.__doc__` at runtime.

Comment: To be more specific, is there a way different than `eval()`?

Comment: This is something that is specific to f-strings as far as I am aware