# How to programatically save pdf of jupyter notebook with a custom, dynamic, file name

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pdf-generation, jupyter

On Windows 10, I am trying to save a Jupyter notebook as a pdf, under a name that will change for every run of the notebook.

Here is what I have so far:

```
name1 = 'July'
name2 = 'August'
jupyter_nb_filename = '{}_vs_{}'.format(name1,name2)
!jupyter nbconvert --output-dir="C:\\mydir\\" --output=jupyter_nb_filename --to pdf --TemplateExporter.exclude_input=True mynotebook.ipynb
```

- **Current behaviour**: Jupyter notebook is stored as "jupyter_nb_filename.pdf"
- **Desired behaviour**. Jupyter notebook to be stored as "July_vs_August.pdf"

I looked in the documentation but could not figure it out.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As the link that @duckboycool references covers, it is the more common/better approach in Jupyter is to use curly brackets to pass Python variables in when using the exclamation point to run shell commands in a notebook, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40932507/8508004).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to prefix the variable name with `$` for it to be interpreted as a variable in a console command. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35497069/passing-ipython-variables-as-arguments-to-bash-commands).

```
!jupyter nbconvert --output-dir="C:\\mydir\\" --output=$jupyter_nb_filename --to pdf --TemplateExporter.exclude_input=True mynotebook.ipynb
```